# Асинхронная обработка элементов очереди (Python)

Tags: python, вконтакте, async-await, очередь, asyncio

Только начал изучать asyncio и появились некоторые вопросы. Можно ли предоставить пример  асинхронной обработки элементов из пополняющейся очереди?
Если говорить конкретно, то пишу бота для VK, в котором все события складываются в очередь, забираются из неё и обрабатываются. За основу беру aiovk, vkbottle и подобное не предлагать.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html

Comment: @andreymal, вероятно, это то, что нужно. Спасибо.